# How to serialize/deserialize in both JSON and XML format in Java?

Tags: java, xml, json

Have a bunch of classes which I need to do serialize and deserialize from/to JSON/XML at the same time. Which library you recommend to this task?

Comment: Tell us more about your constraints - on mobile, performance factors?

Comment: Not on mobile. The data is not large, so performace is not critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for JSON, and [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for XML.  We use them both in a product and they're pretty rugged.  Jackson is very fast.

Update: @radai suggests the Simple XML library, which looks pretty interesting.

Comment: Check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Answer (score 1):

For xml we use simple ([simple.sourceforge.net](http://simple.sourceforge.net))

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a very interesting option.  XStream seems somewhat less flexible, and it's fairly slow.  Simple looks worth checking out!

Comment: @radi:  Check out - http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do both with [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org): core package handles JSON, and [xml-databinding](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-xml-databind) extension module can do XML.

There are other modules that support [BSON](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson) and [CSV](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv), as well; Jackson is becoming a general-purpose data-binding tool.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a good [resource for json](http://www.json.org/java/)

Here's a good [resource for processing xml](http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/)

Comment: Link-only response is highly discouraged.