# how to deserialize data table from wcf post service which is added as a service reference?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

i have written code in wcf to fetch data from sql database . Following is my code

```
string SP_STATE = "SP_STATE";
Select selectOBJ = new Select();
DataTable dt = selectOBJ.selectSTATE(SP_STATE);
string jsonData= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
return jsonData;
```

i have written code in asp.net to fetch data from wcf post service which is added as a service reference but when i am calling from service ..it is giving me error(**Additional information: There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. End element 'root' from namespace '' expected.
Found element 'GetStateListResult' from namespace ''**)

following is my code

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doctorServiceObj.GetStateList()));
STATELISTRESULT objStudent = (STATELISTRESULT)jsonSer.ReadObject(stream);
Response.Write(string.Format("Name = {0} and Address = {1}", objStudent.STATE, objStudent.ROW_ID));
```

Please Suggest me solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform serialization and deserialization of datatables to and from JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165712/how-to-perform-serialization-and-deserialization-of-datatables-to-and-from-json)

Answer (score 0):

please try this at server side:

```
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( doctorServiceObj.GetStateList())));
```

then you can deserilze it in client side like this:

```
var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourType>(responseString);
```

Comment: I facing the same error, can you explain me what is YourType and responseString. I'm serelizing DataTable from WCF is YoutType is going to be DataTable.